# Fullscreen with VideoJS Flash fallback

Tags: html, flash, video, internet-explorer-8, video.js

I am working on a version of VideoJS which uses Flash as a fallback for IE8.  I am aware that IE8 does not support the HTML5 fullscreen API. Does anyone know if this also limits the capabilities of the Flash fallback as well? When clicking on the fullscreen button the video is limited to the size of the browser window rather than taking up the full screen.

Comment: You should add the video.js tag. I'm sure (as the author of video.js) heff could answer this if he sees it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that's the best we can do in IE8. Video.js uses html/css/js for all of the controls and plugins, including in the case of Flash where the html is overlaid on a swf that just handles displaying the video. This is great for the consistency of development, but true fullscreen in IE8 is one limitation. If we were to allow Flash fullscreen, either all the controls and plugins would go  away, or we would have to duplicate **everything** inside of Flash. Sorry if that's disappointing. Hopefully IE8 use will [continue to drop quickly](http://theie8countdown.com).

Comment: Thanks for the response. That makes sense. Since IE9 and IE10 also don't support the HTML5 fullscreen API I assume that will be the same situation for them as well.